# HTML5 style Audio tag with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, audio, webkit

I have to questions here:

First - is there any way to style firefox audio tag like -webkit browsers. For example: I can use `audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel` to change background color.

Second - Is there any way to differ -webkit audio tag from -moz audio tag.

Now I will show you my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/WB7yT/

this is how I style my audio tag for now.
I want to use this, but with firefox `audio { height: 50px; }` is a problem, which is needed for -webkit browsers.

any ideas?

P.S. please don't suggest javascript solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you can't. Chrome is the best browser for using experimental features such as the web audio api or new CSS3 pseudo selectors and other new styling elements.'

adit: you didn't want to use javascript but that is the only way to make a completely stylable player.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll go without height ))